# F# Interactive CsvProvider not defined

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, f#-data

I'm loading FSharp.Data in the interactive console. The library is loaded without any problem:

```
> #r "FSharp.Data.dll";;

--> Referenced 'C:\Users\pw\AppData\Local\Temp\FSharp.Data.dll' (file may be locked by F# Interactive process)

> open FSharp.Data;;
```

However, when I'm trying to initialize `CsvProvider` (defined in `FSharp.Data`) I get the error message saying the type is not defined:

```
> type Stocks = CsvProvider<"C:\Users\pw\Downloads\msft.csv">;;

type Stocks = CsvProvider<"C:\Users\pw\Downloads\msft.csv">;;
--------------^^^^^^^^^^^

stdin(62,15): error FS0039: The type 'CsvProvider' is not defined
```

I thought the problem may be with file and assemblies paths but now I'm using absolute paths and the error remains. On the other hand, I am able to use the CsvProvider when I'm creating a standard, not interactive, project. Any help to make it work in interactive session highly appreciated.

Comment: This is odd - which version of F# are you running?

Comment: I'm running `F# Interactive version 12.0.30110.0`. And F# is 3.0. I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition.

Comment: did you try double backslash: CsvProvider<"C:\\Users\\pw\\Downloads\\msft.csv">?

Comment: Yes, I tried escaping backslash. I've tried verbatim string as well. Same result.

Comment: I created project, added nuget FSharp.Data. Then clickied on FSharp.Data reference and Send to Intractive. It worked for me.

Comment: probably nuget adds some dependent assemblies.

Comment: @Alex I just did that. I created a new solution, installed the library from NuGet manager, and sent it to F# interactive. Works without any problem. I have no idea what was wrong. The only difference from before I can think of is that I used "Send to Interactive" command directly rather than trying to use `#r` directive.

Comment: Are you missing an `open FSharp.Data`?

Comment: @RobertJeppesen No, it's in the first code sample.

Comment: It does not work on my machine with VS 2022. As nice as TypeProviders are,whenever I give them a new try, I do not get them to work. Same error as here, tried with net6 and net48 and both scripting environments.

Answer (score 2):

The warning about file being locked looks worrisome. Can you copy `FSharp.Data` somewhere and reference it using absolute path:

```
\#r @"C:\Poligon\packages\FSharp.Data.2.1.0\lib\net40\FSharp.Data.dll";;
```

Comment: I tried two things: 1) I copied the `dll` to a neutral directory and then referenced it by absolute path. 2) I also added to the console a directory where the dll has been installed by NuGet manager (using `#I` directive) and then referenced it from there. In both cases it resulted in the warning that `file may be locked by F# Interactive process`. Needles to say I'm still not able to access the `CsvProvider` in the console.

Comment: Long shot, but can you use Process Explorer to see what is holding lock on that file? If nothing does, then you can use Process Monitor to monitor what processes are access this file when fsi is running (antivirus maybe?)

Comment: you always get this locking message when you reference dll in interactive, it's normal, it's just mean you can't modify project, producing this dll.

Comment: @MichalMa both the dll and file are locked by `devenv` that is by my instance of Visual Studio and by the interactive console (`Fsi.exe`) which isn what can be expected.

Comment: I had the same problem... even with everything referenced via absolute paths, FSI complained "The type 'CsvProvider' is not defined".
Restarting Visual Studio fixed it, so probably indicates a locking problem.

Answer (score -1):

Downgrade your FSharp.Core to 4.7 and FSharp.Data to 3.3.3. It should work after that.

Comment: The question is from 2014, at that time the F# version was 3.1. Not sure what was the version of FSharp.Data.